# javascript - é possivel utilizando o filter() na condição retornar mais de um id?, passando apenas um valor está retornando ok

Tags: javascript, array

```js
const estados = [{
    id: 1,
    federacao: "Rondônia",
    populacao: 1796460
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    federacao: "Acre",
    populacao: 894470
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    federacao: "Amazonas",
    populacao: 4207714
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    federacao: "Roraima",
    populacao: 631181
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    federacao: "Para",
    populacao: 8690745
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    federacao: "Amapá",
    populacao: 861773
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    federacao: "Tocantis",
    populacao: 1590248
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    federacao: "Maranhão",
    populacao: 7114598
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    federacao: "Piaui",
    populacao: 3281480
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    federacao: "Ceará",
    populacao: 9187103
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    federacao: "Rio Grande do Norte",
    populacao: 3534165
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    federacao: "Paraiba",
    populacao: 4039277
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    federacao: "Pernambuco",
    populacao: 9616621
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    federacao: "Alagoas",
    populacao: 3351543
  },
  {
    id: 15,
    federacao: "Sergipe",
    populacao: 2318822
  },
  {
    id: 16,
    federacao: "Bahia",
    populacao: 14930634
  },
  {
    id: 17,
    federacao: "Minas Gerais",
    populacao: 21292666
  },
  {
    id: 18,
    federacao: "Espirito Santo",
    populacao: 4064052
  },
  {
    id: 19,
    federacao: "Rio de Janeiro",
    populacao: 17366189
  },
  {
    id: 20,
    federacao: "São Paulo",
    populacao: 46289333
  },
  {
    id: 21,
    federacao: "Parana",
    populacao: 11516840
  },
  {
    id: 22,
    federacao: "Santa Catarina",
    populacao: 7252502
  },
  {
    id: 23,
    federacao: "Rio Grande do Sul",
    populacao: 11422973
  },
  {
    id: 24,
    federacao: "Mato Grosso do Sul",
    populacao: 2809394
  },
  {
    id: 25,
    federacao: "Mato Grosso",
    populacao: 3526220
  },
  {
    id: 26,
    federacao: "Goiás",
    populacao: 7113540
  },
  {
    id: 27,
    federacao: "Distrito Federal",
    populacao: 3055149
  }
]

const iduf = [10, 18, 20] // valores passado via post no body

const federacaoFiltrada = estados.filter(estado => estado.id == iduf);

console.log("Estados selecionados")
console.table(federacaoFiltrada)
```

Answer (score -1):

Basta trocar a forma que está fazendo a checagem do filtro..

`<array>.includes` checa se um item está dentro de um array, então você pode utilizá-lo, ficando assim:

```
const federacaoFiltrada = estados.filter(estado => iduf.includes(estado.id));
```

Comment: perfeito!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!